# TIKZ mathematical diagram: arrows should have a common source

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

The following code

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{shadows,matrix,arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}\small\begin{scope}[->,shorten >=3pt,shorten <=3pt]
\matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,row sep=0.5cm, column sep=1cm,outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt]
{                       &                   \\
                        &e_{12}e_{14}e_{25}e_{25}e_{25} \\
e_{14}e_{15}e_{24}e_{25}&e_{12}e_{15}e_{24}e_{25}e_{25} \\
                        &e_{13}e_{14}e_{35}e_{25}e_{25} \\
                        &e_{13}e_{15}e_{34}e_{25}e_{25} \\
                        &e_{13}e_{25}e_{34}e_{25}e_{25} \\};
\path[-] (m-3-1) edge (m-2-2) edge (m-3-2) edge (m-4-2) edge (m-5-2) edge (m-6-2); 
\path[-,red] (m-3-1) edge (m-5-2);
\end{scope}\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces [image].

How can I achieve that all edges from/to a node have a common beginning/ending?
[image]

Comment: Use `(m-3-1.east)` instead of `(m-3-1)` which is equivalent to `(m-3-1.center)`. And `(m-x-x.west)` for right column nodes.

Comment: @Ignasi: Umm, that places the endpoints of edges at the third $e$ (the middle of $e_{14}e_{15}e_{24}e_{25}$) so there is overlapping.

Comment: I tried to say that `(m-3-1)` is equivalent to `(m-3-1.center)`. So you must use `(m-3-1.east)` instead of `(m-3-1)`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are inserting more edges than the necessary. You need 4 black and 1 red. As cited by @Ignasi, you can change the node anchor to `west` and to `east`.

If necessary, just use another `\path` command with a different anchor, if you think that some position is not good. For example, you can use `south` or `south west` and so on.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,matrix,arrows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}\small
    \begin{scope}[->,shorten >=3pt,shorten <=3pt]
    \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,row sep=0.5cm, column sep=1cm,outer sep=0pt,inner sep=0pt]
    {   &                                                         \\
        & e_{12}e_{14}e_{25}e_{25}e_{25}                          \\
          e_{14}e_{15}e_{24}e_{25}&e_{12}e_{15}e_{24}e_{25}e_{25} \\
        & e_{13}e_{14}e_{35}e_{25}e_{25}                          \\
        & e_{13}e_{15}e_{34}e_{25}e_{25}                          \\
        & e_{13}e_{25}e_{34}e_{25}e_{25}                          \\
    };
    \path[-] (m-3-1.east) edge (m-2-2.west) edge (m-3-2.west) edge (m-4-2.west) edge (m-6-2.west); 
    \path[-,red] (m-3-1.east) edge (m-5-2.west);
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

With `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=2ex]
  &e_{12}e_{14}e_{25}e_{25}e_{25} \\
e_{14}e_{15}e_{24}e_{25}
  \ar[ur,dash,start anchor=real east,end anchor=real west]
  \ar[r,dash,start anchor=real east,end anchor=real west]
  \ar[dr,dash,start anchor=real east,end anchor=real west]
  \ar[ddr,dash,start anchor=real east,end anchor=real west,red]
  \ar[dddr,dash,start anchor=real east,end anchor=real west]
  &e_{12}e_{15}e_{24}e_{25}e_{25} \\
  &e_{13}e_{14}e_{35}e_{25}e_{25} \\
  &e_{13}e_{15}e_{34}e_{25}e_{25} \\
  &e_{13}e_{25}e_{34}e_{25}e_{25}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Since all arrows share the same attributes, one can set them in the options to `\begin{tikzcd}` (thanks to Gonzalo Medina for suggesting it):

```
\begin{tikzcd}[
  row sep=2ex,
  arrows=dash,
  start anchor=real east,
  end anchor=real west,
]
  &e_{12}e_{14}e_{25}e_{25}e_{25} \\
e_{14}e_{15}e_{24}e_{25}
    \ar[ur]
    \ar[r]
    \ar[dr]
    \ar[ddr,red]
    \ar[dddr]
  &e_{12}e_{15}e_{24}e_{25}e_{25} \\
  &e_{13}e_{14}e_{35}e_{25}e_{25} \\
  &e_{13}e_{15}e_{34}e_{25}e_{25} \\
  &e_{13}e_{25}e_{34}e_{25}e_{25}
\end{tikzcd}
```

Comment: +1. Nice. Yoor code can be further simplified: `\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=2ex,start anchor=real east,end anchor=real west,arrows=dash]
  &e_{12}e_{14}e_{25}e_{25}e_{25} \\
e_{14}e_{15}e_{24}e_{25}
  \ar[ur]
  \ar[r]
  \ar[dr]
  \ar[ddr,red]
  \ar[dddr]
  &e_{12}e_{15}e_{24}e_{25}e_{25} \\
  &e_{13}e_{14}e_{35}e_{25}e_{25} \\
  &e_{13}e_{15}e_{34}e_{25}e_{25} \\
  &e_{13}e_{25}e_{34}e_{25}e_{25}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}`

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun and practicing, a solution with [`forest`](http://ctan.org/pkg/forest)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
[$e_{14}e_{15}e_{24}e_{25}$, grow'=east, 
        for tree={parent anchor=east,child anchor=west}, l sep=.75cm 
    [$e_{12}e_{14}e_{25}e_{25}e_{25}$] 
    [$e_{12}e_{15}e_{24}e_{25}e_{25}$, calign with current]
    [$e_{13}e_{14}e_{35}e_{25}e_{25}$]
    [$e_{13}e_{15}e_{34}e_{25}e_{25}$, edge={red}]
    [$e_{13}e_{25}e_{34}e_{25}e_{25}$]]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]